# Get access to the first row of a list in R

Tags: r, list

Consider a list in R, for example

```
A=list()
A[[1]]=c(1,2)
A[[2]]=c(3,4)
```

Is it possible to return a vector which gives the first element of each entry of the list (here `c(1,3)`)?

And as a extension: What, if the elements of the list are not just vectors but matrices. Is it possible to get the vector that contains the first element of the second row for each matrix?

Comment: c(A[[1]][1],A[[2]][1])

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
 A=list()
 A[[1]]=c(1,2)
 A[[2]]=c(3,4)
 A[[3]]=c(5,6)

 A
 # [[1]]
 # [1] 1 2

 # [[2]]
 # [1] 3 4

 # [[3]]
 # [1] 5 6
```

I. First Solution using `sapply()` function for just first elements

```
 sapply(A,'[[',1)
 # [1] 1 3 5
```

For Getting lets say 1st, 3rd, 4th elements of each nested list. Not applicable in this example

```
 sapply(A,`[`,c(1,3,4))
```

II. Second Solution using `for` loop

```
 for(i in 1:length(A)){
 print (A[[i]][1])
 }
 # [1] 1
 # [1] 3
 # [1] 5
```

Comment: Thank you. This was just a simple example. My list is much bigger, so I tought maybe there is a function for that without a loop.

Comment: You can use `sapply()` to get the vector form with all the first elements of nested list object.

Answer (score 7):

Try this below:

```
sapply(A, "[", 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do:

```
unlist(lapply(A, "[[", 1))

# [1] 1 3
```

For second element:

```
unlist(lapply(A, "[[", 2))

# [1] 2 4
```

To do that for all:

```
t(sapply(seq_along(A[[1]]), function(x) unlist(lapply(A, "[[", x))))

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
```

Comment: As an extension of my question: What, if the elements of the list are not just vectors, but also matrixes? How could I for example access every first element of the second row of each matrix?

Comment: @fabian92 this is another question. you can post it and see the answers or edit your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant, but you can use as.data.frame() to convert the list to a data frame and then extract the first row.

```
A=list()
A[[1]]=c(1,2)
A[[2]]=c(3,4)
b<-as.vector(as.data.frame(A)[1,])
b

  c.1..2. c.3..4.
1       1       3
```